# Mobile Multi Platform App Development

Tags: cordova, mobile, mobile-application

Is app development in one platform and deploying in multiple platforms a optimal way to proceed. Since there are multiple tools that are available like PhoneGap that helps to do this.

Is there any downside on taking this approach.

If its a good approach to go ahead, Kindly provide the best platform to choose as well for this.

Kindly provide pointers (or) if its already answered, kindly provide links for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way to this.
For a multi-platform project we have used XAMARIN which works well, but you still have to wrap your brain around the different "quirks" and behaviors of each platform.
Phonegap is in my opinion not the way to go if you want to give the users of each platform, the feeling of a real native app, optimized for their desired platform.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Does XAMARIN provide the feeling of a real native app, that is being lacked by PhoneGap?

Comment: Xamarin has an option to use native design tools to create the user interface.  You then hook up that interface to reuse the logic of your code.  You are using the native interface objects from each platform.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Snappii, I think. It's very easy to use, cause they have drag-and-drop editor there so you can make an app without any coding at all. The app then can run on iPhone, iPod, Android and HTML5. 
I like this platform, cause, you know, I'm not an expert in programming, and it helps me very much, though, as all other multi-platform app makers, it has some limitations, but still, for me, it provides richer functionality than many other app builders of that kind. So, I think, you may also like it))

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you can go with the Phonegap. Its a simple and easy method to give each Native apps in all platforms. I personally develop a app which is in PhoneGap and it really reduce my burden a lot. Once i started working on this, its easy to develop a app in all platforms with small modifications in the core.

Answer (score 0):

Again it all depends on the complexity of the application like features, business logic, designs etc. To make the development process more easy and simple, just go ahead with Configure.IT- Online Mobile App Development Platform for building all data driven mobile apps which will suffice your purpose as well without coding efforts. It's 100 % Native code iOS(Swift 3) and android(java)

Please refer - http://www.configure.it/benefits-business/